# Month and year FormHelper error in Cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

i am getting this error , but only in one page , on other page its working fine . why ?

> > echo $this->Form->input('Card.month', array('type' => 'date','autocomplete' => 'off','label' => false,'dateFormat' => 'M', 'empty' => false, 'separator' => ' '));
> >
> > echo $this->Form->input('Card.year', array('type' => 'date','autocomplete' => 'off','label' => false, 'dateFormat' => 'Y', 'empty' => false, 'separator' => ' ', 'minYear' => date('Y'), 'maxYear' => date('Y', strtotime('+20 years'))));

[image]

Comment: I tested Your code and works good on Cake 2.3.6

Comment: You should always state the exact version you are using - in order for us to give a correct answer.

Comment: @kicaj , my question first line >> 

i am getting this error , but only in one page , on other page its working fine . why ?

Comment: @mark i am using latest version , its working on local server , live server but problem on with one page! i have check all code there is no any variable that over-ride that helper function

Comment: solve : need to remove model name ,  'month'  instead of 'Card.month' same as for year

Answer (score 2):

There was an issue with Cake and the FormHelper falsely running into a scalar check if one of those date array keys is not submitted which I recently fixed:
https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/commit/eb13242680731f8c1cf82786670f5fe40d06f6f3

If you check out the current 2.3 head (Master branch!), you will probably not see this notice again. Let me know if that is not the case.

But you should probably use a combined input() here with dateFormat=>MY anyway.

PS: I also just added pretty much your code as tests to disprove that there are issues in the current master branch: https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/commit/290c343a745074f1955dd39f7a83638e144df8d8

UPDATE: I am able to reproduce your error with form data posted. You seem to have forgotten to mention this crucial piece of information

UPDATE2: Fixed it in the current master branch: https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/commit/ee5e8c95dd7306665f6a69316618f3a1848ee088

To explain: You are passing some values down from the controller in your `$this->request->data` array. Those arrays do - in your cae - not contain the specific keys of month and/or year, though. That triggers the error as there was no check in the form helper to assert that omitting those keys worked - which it should have.

Answer (score 1):

Try use `FormHelper::month` (http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/source-class-FormHelper.html#2148-2183) and `FormHelper::year` (http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/source-class-FormHelper.html#2094-2146) instaed of `type=date`

Comment: same problem with year and month helper , but not in other pages , only current